# Trying to find a text file on my desktop with google desktop

Tags: windows-xp, google-desktop-search

I have a file named "job numbers.txt" that I would like to be able to access via google desktop, however google desktop does not find it.

I have my desktop explicitly defined in google desktop's search locations. The file is only 106 bytes, I'm wondering if maybe because it's so small it isn't indexed? I've also tried searching for the content inside the file and it is not finding it that way either.

If it's of any consequence, I'm using latest service pack of Windows XP.

Comment: I can search in:"C:\Documents and Settings\djseng\Desktop" and the file isn't even listed there

Comment: going to try re-indexing again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually re-indexed and I am now able to find the file. :/

Answer (score 0):

Interesting... I have not experienced any problems like this. But i came across [this](http://desktop.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13754) link for troubleshooting. Hope it helps a little. Also, for indexing, if you read through that link, they are telling that all items with atleast 1 byte size are indexed :)

Comment: I've run through the list and the file still isn't "findable"

Answer (score 0):

Try [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/):

> "Everything" is an administrative tool that locates files and folders
>   by filename instantly for Windows. Unlike Windows search "Everything"
>   initially displays every file and folder on your computer (hence the
>   name "Everything"). You type in a search filter to limit what files
>   and folders are displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I get this problem too.  I create .txt notes of my work everyday and I had assumed it would be automatically indexed by Desktop but no. I have it automatically indexing my hard drive so why does it not find my text files? Is this a bug?

Comment: I would assume so, because after I re-indexed it worked... I wonder if altering the notes isn't a big enough change? Maybe drastically changing the size of the file would mark it for re-indexing... /shrug ...or maybe just creating a newly named file each day... just a couple of other ideas i've had but haven't tried yet.